# ErrorException in HasRelationships.php

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Im gettings this error, but i'm not sure is it because of the relationship or something else?

Error

```
ErrorException in HasRelationships.php line 487:
Class 'Company' not found
```

User.php

`public function company(){
        $this->belongsTo('Company', 'user_id');
    }`

Company.php

`public function user(){
        $this->belongsTo('User') ;
    }`

Now my goal is to hide "Create Listing" button in navigation bar, if user doesn't have relation with companies table. I know i can make it with roles or middleware, but my friend send me something like that and told me its easier to make that way.

```
if(count($user->company) > 0)
```

So now i'm trying to figure out how, but still can't figure out how to fix the error.

Navigation view

```
@inject('user', 'App\User')
   @if(count($user->company) > 0)
     <li><a href="{{route('listings.create', [$area])}}">Add listing</a></li>
   @endif
```

///UPDATE

It didn't find class 'Company', because i wasn't using full namespaces in my relationships, but now i'm getting this new error.

Error

```
ErrorException in HasAttributes.php line 403:
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation 

(View: /Users/username/Desktop/laravel/resources/views/layouts/partials/_navigation.blade.php) 
(View: /Users/username/Desktop/laravel/resources/views/layouts/partials/_navigation.blade.php) 
(View: /Users/username/Desktop/laravel/resources/views/layouts/partials/_navigation.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use full namespace in the relationship code:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: Okay something changed, but now i'm getting this `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Comment: Thanks, full namespaces solved the problem and i updated the topic.